# How to get two list together in a object or tuple?

Tags: javascript

I have two lists on my code, one of "id_product" other one of "name_product"

```
for (i in lista_prod) {
  const opt = document.createElement('option');
  for (j in lista_prodname) {

    opt.innerHTML = lista_prodname[j]
  }
  opt.value = lista_prod[i];
  selectprod.appendChild(opt)
}
```

I want to create something iterable that the first index of a list get together with the firt element of the other list and continue until the end

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585370/3082296) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645208/3082296)

Comment: `lista_prod.forEach((value , i) => { const opt = document.createElement('option'); opt.innerHTML =lista_prodname[i];  opt.value = value; selectprod.appendChild(opt) })`

Comment: Actually that was highly simple, i just use 

` for (let i = 0; i < lista_prod.length; i++) {
                const opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = lista_prod[i];
                opt.innerHTML = lista_prodname[i]
                selectprod.appendChild(opt)
                
            }`

Comment: That would work too